# Cassandra nodes cannot gossip (UN and DN node)

Tags: cassandra

I have some problem for cassandra 4.0.3 . Actually i have basic configuration for two nodes in my cluster and there was a no problem in my configuraiton settings, i can connected each node and i was working cluster but i closed one node for along one day after that i could not connect each other again so i saw some problem for example when i write `nodetool describecluster` on terminal window output is same schema version and live:1 - unreachable:1 node then i wanted to try other command, i wrote `nodetool status`  after that the status is  `DN` for other node actually all nodes can run because own status is `UN` on own terminal window and i could not solve this.

I want to say something  from cassandra message. Seed nodes terminal message is

```
WARN  17:31:51 CassandraRoleManager skipped default role setup: some nodes were not ready
INFO  17:31:51 Setup task failed with error, rescheduling
```

like this.

I try a lot of things for example disable-enable gossip , stop ufw, stop firewalld, restart cassandra service, change ip , clean the /var/lib/cassandra folder after that make configuration then service start again and finally run the sudo `lsof -i -P -n` command then find the cassandra pid and kill them then start again.

I started cassandra with `/usr/sbin/ sudo ./cassandra -f -R -Dcassandra.ignore_dc= True` command. That's all i have to say.
Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you described indicate that the nodes cannot gossip with each other. Gossip is the way nodes in a Cassandra cluster communicate with each other and it uses a different protocol compared to CQL (client) connections.

There are two things you need to check:

1. Make sure there is network connectivity between all nodes and that they can communicate with each other on gossip port `7000`. Use Linux tools like `telnet` or `nc` to test the connectivity.
2. Make sure you have NTP installed and running on the nodes.

If there is a large time difference between the nodes, this will prevent them from gossiping with each other. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I checked but there was a no problem. Actually if i uninstall cassandra after that again install cassandra, program run with correctly but i have to solve this problem because i met two times this problem if you say new think i can try this. Also i saw your profile a lot off websites and a lot off question so i trust you :)

Comment: Hearing it worked after you reinstalled tells me you likely mis-configured something and it prevented the nodes from communicating with each other. A new installation means that you had a fresh configuration and so it was working. Without comparing the installations side-by-side, it's impossible for me to determine what went wrong but I'm glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again.Actually i did not change any think in my configuraiton. I installed cassandra and i comminicated each other and i wanted like to use this configuration so i closed one node after that i got a node image. Finally i connected each other again with same configuraiton but i did not connect